# Eclipse C Project Override Make Command with Command Chain

Tags: linux, eclipse

Working under linux for our developement, I have an Eclipse Makefile C Project and I'm trying to override the make command with this so that a custom script I have will run before make to setup additional variables (easier to keep one script in sync than overriding multiple individual project env variables all the time)

Make command: ./setenv.sh && make

Script contents for testing

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "setenv.sh"
```

When running this in Eclipse (build project) I see the script output, but make seems to never get called after the script completes. Perhaps I'm missing something and the script requires a return value of some sort and after running it it returns "false" and the chain doesn't go on but I couldn't find anything online in my searches on how to get this working.

Note: This is on Eclipse 3.5 Galileo

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is probably because `./setenv.sh && make` is a shell command and requires an interpreter to get it executed properly.

I would suggest you to set Make command to:

```
sh -c './setenv.sh && make'
```

### UPD.

To get make targets to be passed as well, one can use `$0` and `$@` provided by the shell:

```
sh -c './setenv.sh && $0 $@' make
```

From [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Invoking-Bash):

> `-c` *string*
>
> Read and execute commands from *string* after processing the options, then exit. Any remaining arguments are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with `$0`.

That is, after Eclipse will append arguments to this command, it would look like:

```
sh -c './setenv.sh && $0 $@' make targets...
```

The shell substitutes `$0` with `make` and `$@` with the rest passed arguments (if any), in the example above they are `targets...`. After all, the actually executed command is:

```
./setenv.sh && make targets...
```

Comment: That worked almost, seems like the build target (all, clean, etc) is excluded from the command and I can't figure out the env variable that holds this information so I could change it to -> sh -c './setenv.sh && make ${target}' or similar

Comment: @David, what's about `sh -c './setenv.sh && $0 $1' make`?

Comment: @David, or, better `sh -c './setenv.sh && $0 $@' make`

Comment: Yes that worked like a charm, perhaps you could explain how the command is expanded by the system for future people like me that are somewhat noobs on command line chaining like this.

Comment: Final command used was "sh -c '. ./setenv.sh && $0 $@' make" as any exported env variables didn't stick so I had to "source" the shell script for them to stick until make is called and all was fine.